# How can I make nb-layout-column center and max width fixed

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css, nebular

[image]

I am working with [Nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/) on an Angular app, and I want to have a single column without a header and footer. I am also using [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) for my CSS and I want to center the column and also add max width to it.

Currently I have something like this:

```
<nb-layout class="place-items-center">
  <nb-layout-column class="max-w-7xl">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

The problem here is that while the max width is applied the alignment is always against start and not center. I have tried every CSS tag with center in its name but nothing.

Nebular's `nb-layout` also has `center` tag but it makes the div too small, but it centers it. There might be a tag I can overwrite through my CSS but I cannot find it.

Comment: Can you add any screenshot?

Comment: @mohitmaroliya I added a photo

Comment: I mean to add separate photos for what you have and what you want to look like.

Comment: As you see in the photo I want the nb-layout-coloumn to be centered rather than placed at `start`

Answer (score 0):

`place-items-center` only works within the context of `display: flex` or `display: grid`

try

```
<nb-layout class="grid place-items-center">
```